# Куда исчезает весь код?

Tags: html, javascript, dom

```
<script>
function mar(direct) {
   var marq =  document.createElement('marquee');
   marq.setAttribute('direction',direct);
   marq.setAttribute('loop','1');
   marq.setAttribute('scrollamount','1');
   marq.setAttribute('scrolldelay','1');
   marq.appendChild(document.getElementById('zone'));
}
</script>
<body style="margin:0">
<div id="zone">
<img onclick="mar('down');" src="1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<img onclick="mar('up');" src="2.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
</div>
</body>
```

После выполнения mar('down') исчезает всё содержимое <body>.Как быть?

Comment: Вы все-таки почитайте про DOM. И про `appendChild`. И внимательность вам не помешает - посмотрите комментарий к предыдущему вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так исчезает наверное потому что вы меняете парента у #zone а вновь созданный элемент не привязан ещё никуда.

добавьте что нить типа

```
document.body.appendChild(marq);
```

Answer (score 2):

[@danpetruk](/users/8694/danpetruk) вы вместо того чтобы прикрепить **`marq` к `#zone`** прикрепляете **`#zone` к `marq`** (при этом открепляя от исходного родителя) по английски же написано:

```
marq.прикрепитьРебёнка(документ.получитьЭлементПоId('zone'));
```

:)

Comment: @Rules напомнило 1С :D

Comment: Кстати, ничто не мешает писать именно так: var документ = document, документ.получитьЭлементПоИд = документ.getElementById; var обертка = документ.получитьЭлементПоИд("wrapper");